# Visualize Geo data in a table

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have document data that contains geoshapes. I also have geoshapes for large areas (e.g. each state). I'm wanting to create a table visualization that separates each row by state. So each row I'm wanting to be a state, and the metric value to be the count of documents that are geo filtered based on the state's geoshape.

When I create a table metric -> Row -> Filters -> Field -> my_geoshape....?

It looks like the filters will only allow me to do filters on the geoshape as if it's text or a number, i.e. 'equals', 'less than', 'greater than', etc. What I'm wanting to do is 'intersects', 'contains', within', etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: Creating a spatial filter in a table is not possible. You can open an issue for this enhancement at https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=Feature_request.md

Comment: As a work around, you can add [spatial filters from Maps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/maps-create-filter-from-map.html#maps-spatial-filters), [save the query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/save-load-delete-query.html), and then import the query in discover or lens.